# Dynamically create objects from function

Tags: swift, oop

Im sorry in advance if my question is too silly, Im new to OOP and programming generally, but i need to figure out a way to create objects dynamically. For example I have a class with init like this

```
   class User {
     var name: String = ""
     var age: Int = 0

   init (name: String, age: Int) {
     self.name = name
     self.age = age
     }
   }
```

I can create new object by using

```
var newUser = User(name: "Joe", age: 21)
```

but i do it manually by hands in code.

How can I automate the process so every time I need to create an object, I pass name, age and object creates automatically with assigning to new variable without mentioning the variable name (for example, there is pattern to for creation a variable, so it does user1, user2, user3 and so on) ? Do I Have to create a specific builder function that creates instances of user?

Comment: Whats the context? So do you want to have a user manager that will create instances of users for you and put them into an array? Do you want to download a Json from a server and then use that data to create users?

Comment: "every time I need to create an object, I pass name, age and object creates automatically" But that is exactly what you are already doing. You are already creating the object perfectly and in the only way possible (by calling the class's initializer), so how is the problem not already solved? Can you give an example of what input and output you want? It is not at all evident what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a large list of users for JSON or something without having to assign a bunch of variable names by hand, I would use a Dictionary and dynamically create the key and value. So a function would look like this

```
var dynamicallyAssignedName: String?
var dynamicallyAssignedAge: Int?

var users: Dictionary<String, User>?
func newUser(name: String, age: Int) {

    var createUser = User(name: dynamicallyAssignedName, age: dynamicallyAssignedAge)

    users[dynamicallyAssignedName] = createUser
}
```

Then you can upload the dictionary fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

You might mean something like this:

```
let arr = [("Matt", 61), ("Alexey", 123)]
let arr2 = arr.map {User(name:$0.0, age:$0.1)}
```